# IF statement causing batch file to crash

Tags: batch-file

G'Day, I am creating a program that tells you if your connected to the internet or not and one crucial part of that program is the following if statement,

```
ping google.com >nul

if %errorlevel% NEQ 0 goto no
rem "no" is not showed in this code example
if %errorlevel% EQU 0 goto yes

:yes
if %a% EQU 1 (
    goto Begin
) else (
    cls
    color a
    echo Connected
    set a=1
)
```

In this context the variable "a" defines connectivity,

For example this piece of code loops so if "a" is equal to "1" we know that we are already connected and this code is not necessary so we should loop back to the ping command. When "a" is "0" we know that we were previously not connected to the internet.

That might be hard to swallow so if you have a question about it ask it below as I can't think of a better explanation

That aside this (as I said in the title) keeps crashing as a batch file (exiting unexpectedly.) I cannot find an answer to this question and it is driving me nuts. (Link to all the code https://docs.google.com/document/d/1-bfAlD2hU8cmLvMorEVzppjqxws80DW5Xnn6jSYDmvY/edit?usp=sharing )

Thanks Much
-R

Comment: What do you mean by *crashing*? Is there an error message? infinite loop? Blue screen of death? Exits unexpectedly with no message? Something else?

Comment: Just at an initial glance, you aren't setting `a` correctly in that last line; you need to get rid of the `%`s.

Comment: Also, you aren't showing us your entire code, but there's a pretty good chance that `a` was never initialized in the first place, making the `if` statement in `:yes` end up being processed as `if EQU 1 (` since uninitialized variables in batch are set to nothing, not 0.

Comment: @SomethingDark I did initialize a in the code but it should by defalt be set to zero anyway. When initialized it is set to zero

Comment: @lurker It exits unexpectedly with no message. I will add this to the question thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the environment variable with the awful name `a` is not initialized before reaching the **IF** command line, the command line expands to:

```
if EQU 1 (
```

This results in exiting execution of batch file processing because of a syntax error.

Windows command interpreter does not crash on execution of the batch file. It clearly indicates the syntax error as it can be seen on running the batch file from within a command prompt window (`cmd.exe` started with option `/K` to **keep** console window open after finishing execution of a batch file or console application) instead of double clicking on the batch file (`cmd.exe` started with option `/C` to **close** window after finishing execution of a batch file or console application).

The solution is:

1. Use a better environment variable name.
2. Initialize the environment variable at top of the batch file.
3. Use a faster string comparison instead of a numeric comparison because environment variables are always of type string and never of type integer. So an integer comparison requires that Windows command interpreter must convert the string value of an environment variable to an integer as well as the string `1` for doing the integer comparison.

Here is your batch code rewritten:

```
@echo off
set "ConnectionState=0"

rem Send only 1 echo request with a timeout of 2000 ms to google.com.
%SystemRoot%\System32\ping.exe -n 1 -w 2000 google.com >nul 2>nul
if errorlevel 1 goto NoConnection

if "%ConnectionState%" == "1" goto Begin
cls
color a
echo Connected
set "ConnectionState=1"
goto :EOF

:NoConnection
echo There is no connection to world wide web.

:Begin
echo There is a connection to world wide web.
```

It is advisable to specify console applications like `ping` always with full path and with file extension to make the batch file independent on the environment variables **PATH** and **PATHEXT**.

It is advisable to ping `google.com` just once with a definite timeout instead of 3 times as by default.

It is advisable not using `%ERRORLEVEL%` (immediate expansion) or `!ERRORLEVEL!` (delayed expansion) but use `if errorlevel 1 ...` which means if exit code of previous application or command is greater or equal 1 or use `if not errorlevel 1 ...` which means if exit code of previous application or command is less than 1 which is equal 0 for all **standard** Windows commands and executables. (Applications should never exit with a negative value. It is possible but not recommended whether on Windows nor on Linux or Mac.) See also the very old Microsoft support article [Testing for a Specific Error Level in Batch Files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/69576) being 100% correct for MS-DOS to latest version of Windows 10.

The double quotes on **IF** command line are included in the string comparison. That makes it possible to have environment variable `ConnectionState` not defined at all as the command line expands in this case to:

```
if "" == "1" goto Begin
```

This command line is correct as there is one argument on left and one on right side of the equal operator as required. `EQU` can be used also instead of `==` but requires enabled command extensions which of course are enabled by default.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `cls /?`
- `color /?`
- `echo /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `ping /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for an explanation of `>nul` and `2>nul`.

And a batch **script** being interpreted by `cmd.exe` with syntax checking during execution is **NOT** a **program** which source code is compiled by a compiler to native CPU instructions with syntax checking during compilation state. It is not possible to compile a program which references a variable not defined at all. (But it is possible to compile a program which has a defined variable not initialized before evaluation resulting in undefined behavior or an exception.)

---

**Extra information about comparing values with IF**

The **IF** equal operator `==` results always in a string comparison while operator `EQU` first always tries an integer comparison and performs also a string comparison if this is not possible as it can be proven with:

```
@echo off
if 00 == 0  (echo 00 is equal 0 on using ==)  else (echo 00 is different 0 on using ==)
if 00 EQU 0 (echo 00 is equal 0 on using EQU) else (echo 00 is different 0 on using EQU)
```

The output on execution is:

```
00 is different 0 on using ==
00 is equal 0 on using EQU
```

In the batch code above the double quotes around the arguments `%ConnectionState%` and `0` can be safely removed if it is guaranteed by appropriate code that the environment variable `ConnectionState` is always defined with value `0` or `1` before the **IF** command line is reached on processing the batch file line by line by Windows command interpreter.

I added the double quotes to make it clear for everybody that strings are compared because the double quotes of both arguments are compared as well.

The `==` operator of **IF** could be coded in **C** for example with this code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    if(argc != 3)
    {
        puts("Error: This compare demo requires exactly two parameters.");
        return 2;
    }

    /* Note: The startup code added by used compiler to executable being
             executed before calling function main removes most likely
             the surrounding double quotes on the argument strings.
             Specify the arguments in form \"value\" to compare
             the arguments with surrounding double quotes. */
    printf("Compare %s with %s.\n",args[1],args[2]);

    if(strcmp(args[1],args[2]) == 0)
    {
        puts("The strings are equal.");
        return 0;
    }

    puts("The strings are different.");
    return 1;
}
```

So the difference on using `"%ConnectionState%" == "0"` versus `%ConnectionState% == 0` is that the function `strcmp` has to compare 4 versus 2 bytes including the terminating null byte. This does not make a real difference as it could be proven by modifying the code above and run `strcmp` for example 100.000.000 times in a loop and measure the execution time for this again and again done compare in caches of the core/processor.

For completeness the equivalent **C** code for operator `EQU`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    char* psEnd;
    long int lArgument1;
    long int lArgument2;

    if(argc != 3)
    {
        puts("Error: This compare demo requires exactly two parameters.");
        return 2;
    }

    /* Note: The startup code added by used compiler to executable being
             executed before calling function main removes most likely
             the surrounding double quotes on the argument strings.
             Specify the arguments in form \"value\" to compare
             the arguments with surrounding double quotes. */
    printf("%s EQU %s\n",args[1],args[2]);

    lArgument1 = strtol(args[1],&psEnd,0);
    if(*psEnd != '\0')
    {
        if(strcmp(args[1],args[2]) == 0)
        {
            puts("The strings are equal.");
            return 0;
        }
        puts("The strings are different.");
        return 1;
    }

    lArgument2 = strtol(args[2],&psEnd,0);
    if(*psEnd != '\0')
    {
        if(strcmp(args[1],args[2]) == 0)
        {
            puts("The strings are equal.");
            return 0;
        }
        puts("The strings are different.");
        return 1;
    }

    if(lArgument1 == lArgument2)
    {
        printf("The integers %ld and %ld are equal.\n",lArgument1,lArgument2);
        return 0;
    }
    printf("The integers %ld and %ld are different.\n",lArgument1,lArgument2);
    return 1;
}
```

It can be already seen here on comparing this C code for demonstrating `EQU` behavior with the C code above for demonstrating `==` behavior that an integer comparison caused by using `EQU` results in more CPU instructions being executed than on doing a string compare with using `==` operator. On running the application in single step mode also into the standard library functions [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) and [strtol](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/) it is even clearer that the processor has to do many more instructions to run an integer comparison in batch file than a string comparison.

This second application written in **C** demonstrates perfect what happens often unexpected for batch file writers on using numbers with 1 or more leading zeros in batch file on comparing values with `EQU` or using them in an arithmetic expression, i.e. in string after `set /A`.

For example compile above code to `equ.exe` and run following:

```
@echo off
equ.exe \"08\" \"08\"
equ.exe 08 8
equ.exe 14 14
equ.exe 014 014
equ.exe 0x14 0x14
equ.exe 0x14 20
equ.exe 0x14 \"20\"
```

The result I get with `equ.exe` compiled with gpp 4.7.3 (DJGPP package) is:

```
"08" EQU "08"
The strings are equal.
08 EQU 8
The strings are different.
14 EQU 14
The integers 14 and 14 are equal.
014 EQU 014
The integers 12 and 12 are equal.
0x14 EQU 0x14
The integers 20 and 20 are equal.
0x14 EQU 20
The integers 20 and 20 are equal.
0x14 EQU "20"
The strings are different.
```

The first comparison `"08" EQU "08"` is executed as string comparison because of `"` in both arguments.

The second comparison `08 EQU 8` is finally also executed as string and not as integer comparison because first argument starts with a leading 0 and is therefore interpreted by function `strtol` with third parameter `base` being `0` as octal number which is invalid because of containing the digit 8. Valid octal numbers have only digits in range 0-7. So string to long integer conversion fails and for that reason a string comparison is executed for `08` compared with `8`.

The third comparison `14 EQU 14` is executed as integer comparison with both numbers being interpreted decimal.

The fourth comparison `014 EQU 014` is executed also as integer comparison, but with both numbers being interpreted octal.

The fifth comparison `0x14 EQU 0x14` is executed again as integer comparison, but with both numbers being interpreted hexadecimal explaining twice `20` as output number.

So it is advisable to run always a string comparison of two values in batch files wherever possible with using operator `==` and without or with using explicitly surrounding double quotes.

It is absolutely useless to measure time differences on `==` versus `EQU` using a batch file because the time needed by Windows command interpreter to parse the command lines in batch file before executing the **IF** condition is **many** times the amount of time required for the compares itself as demonstrated by the compiled C/C++ code used internally.

Of course this also means using `==` or `EQU` does not make a real difference for the user regarding total time needed to accomplish the task done with the batch file. But for other reasons than execution time using `==` or `EQU` makes often a difference.

Comment: I haven't read your entire answer. But your point 3 regarding timing of int comparison vs string comparison is wrong. I compared timing of 1 million string comparisons vs 1 million int comparisons, and could not detect a difference. The loop without IF took ~2 sec, and the loop with IF comparison took ~6 sec regardless whether doing string or int comparison. That means 1 million comparisons in 4 sec. Even if one were twice as fast as the others, who cares? Saving a few microseconds per comparison is meaningless when there are other parts of the script that are much slower.

Comment: @dbenham You are right. For a person there is no noticeable difference if Windows command interpreter calls twice [strtol](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/) to convert the two arguments to signed 32-bit integers and then compare the integers or use [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) and detects on second byte compare if the strings are not equal. However, the number of CPU instructions to execute is for the integer comparison much larger than for the string comparison, but on modern PCs executed nevertheless so fast that not noticeable.

Comment: Thanks @Mofi for the very long and detailed answer. How long did it take you to write that?

Comment: @RickyGonce I have not looked on clock, but it was definitely more than 30 minutes. Most of my answers are long for being as complete as possible in hope the readers really study the answer, learn from it, avoid making same mistakes again and so write their next code better.